# Create Python graphviz Digraph with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pandas-groupby, graphviz

I am trying to make a diagram tree in graphviz.Digraph, I am using Pandas dataframe.
By the below query, I am getting the processid's and their dependents id's in a form of a dictionary

```
dependent = df.groupby('dependent_processid')['Processid'].apply(list).to_dict()
print(dependent)

#output:
{6720: [6721], 6721: [6722, 6724, 6725], 6725: [6723, 6726], 6753: [7177]}
```

But I want the data in below format:

```
          6720-> {6721}
          6721-> {6722, 6724, 6725}
          6725-> {6723, 6726}
....and so on...
```

Can someone please help me return pandas dataframe output in such format?

Comment: try this : `dependent = df.groupby('dependent_processid')['Processid'].apply(set).to_dict()` OR `dict(zip(dependent.keys(), map(set, dependent.values())))`

Comment: Thanks man for the help, any idea how can I put that arrow in between key and value?

Comment: with printing? ?

Comment: Can we do it with return statement in a function?

Comment: I can not understand, please send example or doc from what you want

Comment: I completely suck at this but something like this:

def demo():

    dependent = df.groupby('dependent_processid')['Processid'].apply(set).to_dict()

    for i in dependent:
        
        value = (i+"->"+dependent_processid)

demo()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wanting this:

```
def demo(k,v): 
    return f'{k} -> {v}'

dependent = df.groupby('dependent_processid')['Processid'].apply(set).to_dict()  
for k, v in dependent.items():
    print(demo(k,v))
```

Output:

```
6720-> {6721}
6721-> {6722, 6724, 6725}
6725-> {6723, 6726}
...
```